# How to create conditional ProxyPass?

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

I have the following config for one of the sites-available `.conf` file.
Its configure to load the `ghost` blog if you hit `blog.example.com`.
Somehow its causing `example.com` to serve up the blog as well. But thats fine too.

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
  ServerName blog.example.com
  ServerAdmin admin80@example.com
  ProxyPass        /  http://localhost:2368/
  ProxyPassReverse /  http://localhost:2368/
</Virtualhost>
```

So I just installed `phpmyadmin` and I realized I can't access it with `http://example.com/phpmyadmin`. Accessing that page will bring up ghost's 404 page not found instead.

So I guess I need some conditional `ProxyPass` to ignore `/phpmyadmin` ?
I tried the following by it doesn't work too.

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
  ServerName blog.example.com
  ServerAdmin admin80@example.com
  ProxyPass        /phpmyadmin  http://localhost/phpmyadmin
  ProxyPassReverse /phpmyadmin  http://localhost/phpmyadmin
  ProxyPass        /  http://localhost:2368/
  ProxyPassReverse /  http://localhost:2368/
</Virtualhost>
```

Apache just hang and I have to restart it when I hit `http://example.com/phpmyadmin`.

**Update**:

I tried the following, and it loads up `phpmyadmin` login page. Just added `:80` after localhost. and give a specific domain name for the virtual host instead of `*`.

```
<Virtualhost blog.example.com:80>
  ServerName blog.example.com
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com
  ProxyPass        /phpmyadmin  http://localhost:80/phpmyadmin
  ProxyPassReverse /phpmyadmin  http://localhost:80/phpmyadmin
  ProxyPass        /  http://localhost:2368/
  ProxyPassReverse /  http://localhost:2368/
</Virtualhost>
```

Problem now is, it redirects to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?token=8fa78a71a166399749b58cd3cb66b7f2` instead. Probably some configuration with `phpmyadmin` I guess.

Comment: are you getting any error log?

Comment: the proxy thing works now. but redirection after login seems to be wrong.

Comment: Note: Don't forget to set `ProxyRequests Off` to prevent the public use of your server as a proxy server.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Cool. I'm not aware of that. So do I just include it before the closing `</Virtualhost>` tag?

Comment: I usually have it near the start of the VirtualHost directive, but I don't really think it matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `!` target to prevent a location to be proxied:

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
  DocumentRoot     /path/to/parent/of/phpmyadmin
  ProxyPass        /phpmyadmin !
  ProxyPass        /  http://localhost:2368/
  ProxyPassReverse /  http://localhost:2368/
</Virtualhost>
```

This will proxy all requests to `localhost:2368`, except those to phpmyadmin.

Of course you'll have to set a document root, otherwise phpmyadmin won't be found.

Comment: Cool. This is the easiest solution and it solved the redirection to localhost after logging in to `phpmyadmin` too. So the redirection was caused by the proxy thing instead of some configuration.